# Jquery ajax failing only for some users (ajax response 0)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have an ajax-based login system. The user types in their username/password and submits. This is fired asynchronously to a php script that validates etc and then logs the user in or passes back an error message in json.

The issue is that the ajax call is returning an error for a few users but not most. Weirder, when I try to debug by logging in as those users, it works fine using my own system. It seems linked to their specific setup somehow.

To debug I have the jquery ajax error handler email me the error data when logging in fails (along with some browser info). But the ajax errors I'm seeing are 'undefined'.

I'm at a loss as to how to proceed fixing this or further debugging it. I've proven that this isn't linked to a specific version of a browser, or a same origin issue. Any insight into this would be appreciated. Here's my code:

*UPDATE* I've managed to narrow the problem down to an ajax status response of 0. Some browsers are just stopping the process before it sends, but it's not consistent, leading me to believe it is some sort of plugin or extension that's causing the issue. But it's none of the obvious culprits - noscript, adblocker, etc.

```
$('#loginMain').on('submit', '#loginForm, #resetForm', function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); //don't submit the actual form
    $('#loginExtra').addClass('ajaxloader-circle'); //loading spinner
    var type = $(this).attr('id');
    var submitType = type.replace('Form', '');
    var uploadData = new FormData($("#" + submitType + "Form")[0]);  //get the form data          
    uploadData.append('token', '<?php echo $_SESSION['token']; ?>'); //prevent csrf 

    jQuery.ajax({
        url: 'https://www.example.com/ajaxfiles/loginProcess.php',
        data: uploadData,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) { //on success, reload or present error message
            $('#loginExtra').removeClass('ajaxloader-circle');
            if (data['state'] == false) { //show error data if it failed
                $('#loginFeedback').html('<div style="color:red; text-align: center;">' + data['msg'] + '</div>'); //output any error messages
                $('#loginProcessing').html('');
            } else {
                $('#signupDynamic').html('Success! Reloading...');
                $('#signupFeedback').html('');
                $('#signupProcessing').html('');
                if (submitType == 'login') { //reload on successful login
                    var url = window.location.pathname;
                    var page = url.substr(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
                    if (page != 'login') {
                        location.reload();
                    } else { //logging in on the login page
                        window.location.href = "https://www.example.com"; //redirect to home
                    }
                } else { //output on succesful reset
                    $('#loginFeedback').html('<div style="color:green; text-align: center;">' + data['msg'] + '</div>'); //output any error messages
                    $('#resetForm').html('');
                }
            }
        },
        error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown){ //on fail, email me what went wrong
            var browser = '<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']; ?>'; 
            var errorText = textStatus + '|' + xhr.responseText + '|' + xhr.statusText +  '|' + xhr.readyState +  '|' + errorThrown + '|' + browser;
            $.post("https://www.example.com/ajaxfiles/errorTracker.php", {data: errorText, token: '<?php echo $_SESSION['token']; ?>'}, function(data) {
                window.location.href = "https://www.example.com/login.php";
            }, "text");
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: clearly example code, so, in real code is `url: 'https://www.example.com/ajaxfiles/loginProcess.php',` cross origin or same origin - you state there's no "same origin issue", but I wonder if there's a cross origin issue instead

Comment: failing for some users, javascript, umm  browser issue?

Comment: The page users log on from is https://www.example.com. The ajax file that is requested is in https://www.examples.com/ajaxfiles/loginProcess.php. As far as my (likely limited) understanding of cross/same-origin this shouldn't violate the same-origin policy, right?

Comment: Thanks ArtisticPhoenix. Still not convinced that it's NOT a browser issue, but the debug emails I'm getting are showing at least two different browser types having this same problem. I also used the latest version of Firefox (that was one of the browsers) and logged in fine.

Comment: can you forcefully create error and debug why the email is not working. if there is error in that code, fixing it may give you help to solve your problem

Comment: Please check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to confirm that this WAS in fact caused by a cross-origin issue, which I had ruled out.

The user was somehow navigating to https://example.com (a redirect to www that should have been firing wasn't) which caused issues when the ajax call was sent to https://www.example.com.

Thanks for all the answers. They helped me narrow this down finally.

Answer (score 1):

I will post it as an answer, because it's too long and can not be properly formatted as a comment.

My **guess** is that the problem starts in here:

```
uploadData.append('token', '<?php echo $_SESSION['token']; ?>');
```

When `$_SESSION['token']` is undefined, `PHP` throws an error (notice) that breaks the javascript code as it contains new line character.

The same happens in your debug line:

```
$.post("https://www.example.com/ajaxfiles/errorTracker.php", {data: errorText, token: '<?php echo $_SESSION['token']; ?>'}, function(data) {
```

There is an easy way to check it out... just add on the top (that may not work in certain circumstances):

```
<?php
   error_reporting(0);
?>
```

or replace the given lines with:

```
uploadData.append('token', '<?php echo (isset($_SESSION['token']) ? $_SESSION['token'] : 'SESSION TOKEN IS NOT SET!!!'); ?>');
```

and

```
$.post("https://www.example.com/ajaxfiles/errorTracker.php", {data: errorText, token: '<?php echo (isset($_SESSION['token']) ? $_SESSION['token'] : 'SESSION TOKEN IS NOT SET!!!'); ?>'}, function(data) {
```

Oh and this line as well, because `HTTP_USER_AGENT` may not be defined.

```
var browser = '<?php echo (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] : 'USER AGENT NOT DEFINED!'); ?>';
```

Comment: This didn't turn out to be the issue. Users are receiving an error code 0 when the ajax request fails, meaning the browser isn't even sending the request to the loginProcess page. But it's not specific to a browser version - two different people using the exact same browser will have different experiences.